# Add a custom field to multiple objects

Tags: custom-field, salesforce-id, externalid, external-lookup

I am working on an assignment to populate the data in a developer
sandbox with production data. This activity involves me in populating
data for over 50 objects. I am planning to create an external Id field
on all objects to store the Id of the records created (A common
approach to populate data in sandbox). So, I need to add a custom
external id field as Production_Id__c on all objects. Is there a way
to add this custom field to multiple objects programmatically, using
Ant or something else?

EDIT:== I finally ended up manually adding the external Id fields to
each objects. Tried the following.

1. Installed Bulk Object Field Creator App from Salesforce Appexchange
   and it worked fine for 10 objects. It appears that the free version is
   limited only for 10 objects.
2. Tried the Ultra Schema Builder App from Salesforce Appexchange and
   it did not work as expected. Had it worked fine, my job would have
   been much easier.
3. Tried Ant Deploy - Got a message saying tools.jar not found as I
   only had JRE. I do not have admin rights on my work laptop and hence
   had to try with the portable JDK. The ANT issue regarding the
   tools.jar is resolved. However, trying to deploy with ANT threw the
   error message "Userid/Password is invalid or locked out". I am behind
   a proxy and my password has special characters ($). Tried escaping the
   $ sign with \$, \$ and also %24 and none of these work (with or
   without security token). Then logged into Salesforce org, found the
   Session Id with the statement UserInfo.getSessionId() and changed the
   build.properties to use the SessionId instead of username and password
   and then got the error message "Failed to send request to Salesforce".

After trying so many options, I finally ended up adding the external
id fields manually to all objects. It was time consuming, but I spent
more than this time doing the research.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming all the objects are already created, you could create a file that simply contains the one field definition you need, copy it, and deploy it. I'd say this task is probably easiest with Ant, but you could conceivably do it in an IDE as well.

First, set up your package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```

And in your objects folder, create a *CustomObject__c.object* file with the following contents (adjust to suit your own needs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<fields>
        <fullName>Comments__c</fullName>
        <description>Add your comments about this object here</description>
        <inlineHelpText>This field contains help text for this object</inlineHelpText>
        <label>Comments</label>
        <length>32000</length>
        <type>LongTextArea</type>
        <visibleLines>30</visibleLines>
</fields>
</CustomObject>
```

Next, just copy the file over and over again:

```
$ cp CustomObject__c.object CustomObject2__c.object
$ cp CustomObject__c.object CustomObject3__c.object
  ... as many more as you need
```

Finally, do your deployment:

```
ant deploy
```

Here's a [pre-configured repo](https://github.com/brianmfear/forcedotcom-metadata-fields-example) that you can use to get started.

Comment: Two more things, 
1) You also need to include `<externalId>true</externalId>` if you wanna add it as an external ID
2) By default, no profile can view the field and you have either set the security settings manually or through the ANT by creating the similar setup like above for profiles

Comment: @BalajiPooruli We (answerers) don't get notified of edits, just comments. You probably could have used the [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com), which lets you create a package and upload it as a ZIP file. I could make a demo for you if you'd like?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, could you please share a demo of doing this with the workbench?

Comment: @BalajiPooruli I created a repo that demonstrates how it's done. The link is in the answer.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, I tried the deployment with workbench and it failed with the error mesage " Must specify a non-empty label for the customObject".

Comment: @BalajiPooruli You need to already have the custom objects before you can deploy them. Otherwise, you'll have to specify all the required values, including fullName, pluralLabel, sharingModel, and so on. They should not be required if you already have the objects in your org.

Comment: Hi, The custom object is already there in the developer sandbox env. I am just trying to add an external id field with the name Production_Id__c which will facilitate the data load from production.

Comment: No updates yet? All the standard and custom objects were transferred from production to the DEV sandbox when I did the refresh. I needed to add the custom external Id to the objects that I needed to populate the data and that is not working.

Comment: @BalajiPooruli I presumed this worked in the Metadata API, but I've actually been using Salesforce DX, which does support this format. Unfortunately, it looks like we'd need a script to include the label, plural label, and any other required properties.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I ended up doing the following.  1. Retrieve the metadata of all custom objects and all profiles using the ANT retrieve task. 2. Manually add the custom field entries for Production_Id__c in all *.object file in the objects folder. 3. Modified the package.xml to include the custom objects and the custom fields (Production_Id__c) and ran the ANT deploy task. Finally, I did another ANT deploy for profiles alone with rollbackOnError=false in the build.xml. I tried to just deploy the Admin.profile, but got some error. After deploying all profiles, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Recently found an heroku app https://fieldcreator.herokuapp.com that can be used to create custom fields easily on Salesforce objects. Only caveat is that once the fields are added in salesforce, we need to go to the fields and set the visibility to "true" for the profiles that we want this field to be shown for.