# CPQ Custom field creation in bulk

Tags: cpq

Is there an easy way to create custom fields in bulk on a managed package object?

I created 200 custom fields on the product object. I need the exact same fields on the managed package (Salesforce CPQ) object Product Option and Quote Line. I tried via Mavensmate or Eclipse but the managed package objects are not visible in these tools.

Comment: You can try the solution suggested here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/153621/16304. Not sure if it works for Managed Object but worth giving a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the managed objects with aside.io push, edit the object name (It doesn't include namespace by default) and then copy and paste your fields into the file, rezip it and upload back through aside or workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a bulk field creator can be accessed [here](https://fieldcreator.herokuapp.com/).  You can create fields on different objects with the same API name easily.